# PowerBI json web.contents for new column

Tags: json, powerbi

Im trying to get a new column into powerbi, i have a table with alliance_id and i want a new column which would be filled with names of the alliances
this is what i have:

```
AllianceName = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://esi.evetech.net/dev/alliances/" & 'eveskuska attackers'\[alliance_id\]))\[name\]
```

but for some reason it doesnt work.
this is an example of one of the alliances:
https://esi.evetech.net/dev/alliances/1041482450
i want just the name from this to be in the new column

it just says that:

> json.document, and web.contents isnt a function and [name] is syntax error